# c++ - malloc casting error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, casting, malloc

Everyones suggesting not to cast while allocating a pointer here, [do I cast result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But my below non-casted code produce compiler error in VS-2013. Why!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main(){
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);  // compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler error is,

> 1 IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize
>   an entity of type "int *"

Comment: Considering that you posted with the C++ tag: what is unclear to you? C++ isn't C. In this case the implicit conversion from `void*` to `T*` which is supported in C is not supported in C++.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` and friends in C++. If you need a runtime changeable container use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). If the size is fixed at compile-time use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If you are required to use pointers, use *smart pointers* (like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)). And if you are forced to use raw non-owning pointers, use `new` or `new[]` instead.

Comment: If this is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193732/how-to-free-dynamic-array-of-structure-in-c), that one was tagged with C. This is C++. C and C++ are two different languages, with different behavior and semantics.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude. Its clear now.

Comment: In C++ you should not use `malloc`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Errm if you use `new` with a raw pointer is it not then *by definition* an *owning* pointer?

Comment: @Galik The smart pointers have ownership semantics. Raw pointers do not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The way I understand it is *ownership* refers to the pointer that is responsible for the destruction of the object it points to. So raw pointers can be *owners* but because you have to delete the objects they own manually they are unreliable. So the rule is to avoid *owning* raw pointers. An example of non-owning raw pointers would be an iterator pointing to an element that is owned by something else (a container, smart pointer or (hopefully not) another raw pointer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice in the other question is strictly for `C` only.

In `C++`, you need the cast, since `C++` does not allow *implicit* conversion of a `void*` pointer to any other pointer type.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed the TAG.