# Malloc in C Programming - incompatible pointer types

Tags: c

What is the difference between ptr->Name = (struct rec*)malloc(sizeof(struct rec)); from  ptr->Name = malloc(sizeof(struct rec)); Why is it I'm receiving an error whenever I include (struct rec*) on malloc.

```
struct rec {
 char *Name;
}emp[100];

int main() {

int x;
int i;

struct rec *ptr = NULL;
ptr = emp;

printf("Enter Number of Clients: ");
scanf("%d", &x);
getchar();

for(i=0; i!=x; i++)
{
printf("Enter Name: ");
//I'm receiving an error whenever I add this
ptr->Name = (struct rec*)malloc(sizeof(struct rec));

//Code below is working
ptr->Name = malloc(sizeof(struct rec));
```

Comment: `ptr->Name` is a `char *`, not a `struct rec *`.  You probably intend to allocate to just `ptr`.  The second `malloc()` then allocates storage for the name (8 bytes if you're lucky; 4 if you're not) for the name in `ptr[0]`.

Comment: Your allocation sizeof is wrong too

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193926/c-malloc-casting-error

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct rec {
 char *Name;
}emp[100];`  it is best to separate a struct definition from any instances of that struct

Comment: regarding: `ptr = emp;` results in `ptr` pointing to an array of `struct rec`.  Then `ptr->Name = (struct rec*)malloc(sizeof(struct rec));` should be saying: `ptr[0].Name = (struct rec*)malloc(sizeof(struct rec));`  Note that `Name` is a pointer to character, not a pointer to an instance of a `struct rec`  The result is the compiler outputs an error message

Answer (score 3):

`ptr->Name` is of type `char *`.

`ptr->Name = (struct rec*)malloc(sizeof(struct rec))`  explicitly converts the return value from `malloc()` to a `struct rec *`.    A `struct rec *` cannot be implicitly converted to a `char *`, so the assignment to `ptr->Name` is invalid.

If there is a preceding `#include <stdlib.h>` in your code, `ptr->Name = malloc(sizeof(struct rec))`  works because `malloc()` return `void *`, and a `void *` can be implicitly converted to any pointer type, including to a `char *`.     Without the preceding `#include <stdlib.h>` (or another header which provides a declaration of `malloc()`, the conversion is also invalid.

`void *` is the ONLY pointer type in C that can be converted implicitly to another pointer type.  Hence the difference between your two options.

The argument of `malloc()` is also wrong  i.e. `sizeof(struct rec)` should not be used to dynamically allocate an array of `char`, in most circumstances.